# Write a file with the version number during Heroku deployment

Tags: git, heroku, deployment, semantic-versioning

I want the current code version to be available as a variable at runtime in my express/node.js project running on Heroku.

In the development environment I use a [git describe node module](https://github.com/intellifi-nl/node-git-describe) and have it give me a semver string, but in the production Heroku environment there is no git repository, and no `git` binary anyway.

The way I've gone about solving this in the past, though in non-Heroku environments, was to write a `version` file in the project's root directory with this data as a string, and then have the application load this in rather than invoking `git` all the time. In most of these cases `git` did exist and we were in a real repository in production, so those were easy. Where `git` was not available, or the environment wasn't a full repository (didn't have tags, or was a shallow clone) I did still have the commit's SHA hash at deployment time, provided by the deployment tool, and so wrote an unpleasant script which ran and used it during deployment. It queried Github's API for tags, found a matching one if possible, and wrote the tag name to the `version` file.

Ideally I want a semver string based on the current tag and offset. In particular, in node with the above-mentioned package I run this:

```
var version = require('git-describe').gitDescribeSync();
return version.semverString || version.raw;
```

(In a pinch, `git describe --dirty --tags --always` would also be acceptable.)

What's a good way to achieve this? Is the current tag name or commit hash or anything like that available (such as in an environment variable) at deployment time on Heroku, which I could then use during the build process to write a file or similar? That'd be messy but it'd work. Or is there something better?

Comment: Using what language / framework? For example, [`setuptools_scm`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools_scm/1.0.0) would probably help you meet your needs if you are working in Python, but will be useless for other languages. Also, is writing a file in your project's root directory _really_ your goal? Or do you simply think that's the solution to another problem, e.g. showing the output of `git describe` in the footer of your site? See the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Excellent points; I'll update the question.

Comment: Perhaps one of these will help? https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-describe https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-rev

Comment: @Chris, I don't think you understood the question. I mentioned that I already use the `git-describe` node package in development (I even gave the code I use to call it), and that the production environment, which is where I want to get the version, is on Heroku where there is no git binary or full repository. These packages don't work without those. Or are you suggesting that it's possible to have this run on the local side somehow during deployment, and have the output sent to the remote? If so, how?

Comment: I missed that you are already using one of the packages I mentioned. I certainly do not have a complete idea of a solution for you; I have very little experience with Node.js (though I have extensive experience with Git and quite a lot with Heroku). Hopefully somebody more knowledgeable with your exact tech stack will have a better solution for you.

Comment: To be honest I think the only part of the tech stack which actually matters here is Heroku.